# How does a flex sensor work

Tags: resistors, sensor

On what principle and how
I know that it is a variable resistor, but what principle does it work on, like change in area or pressure..., and maybe explain it in context to mainly available off the shelf ones.
I searched everywhere(online, offline...), but nowhere could I find principle of operation :/

Example - maybe [this](http://www.amazon.in/Robo-India-Flex-Sensor-2-2/dp/B0122XCCUIhttp://www.amazon.in/Robo-India-Flex-Sensor-2-2/dp/B0122XCCUI?tag=googinhydr18418-21&tag=googinkenshoo-21&ascsubtag=b6906995-5ed9-4539-b3b6-677f0b197fea)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strain_gauge

Comment: @v.m. , thank you for pointing out, maybe give an example in context of, off the shelf one. That would be great!

Comment: You provide an example, and we explain how it works.  How about that, @yawar ?

Comment: @NickAlexeev ok, nick I guess I'll give an example, I'll add it to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flex sensor you linked to uses flexible conductive ink printed on flexible base forming a resistor. It works when bent with the ink on the outside of the curve.  When bent, the conductive layer is stretched and thus extends,  resulting in reduced cross section (imagine stretching a rubber band). This reduced cross section and increased length results in an increased resistance,  which can be measured.

All strain gauges work pretty much the same way except for the mechanical design. You must have already read this on Wikipedia.

I've also read somewhere that micro cracks are temporarily formed in the stretched conductive layer leading to a larger increase in resistance. I can't seem to find a reference to it now.